# how to scale horizontal database

Tags: database, scalability, citus

I'm developing an app that consumes web api. If you have too many users and the database server starts to slow down. I would like some tips how to climb it. It was insane they control everything by the application. I have not yet chosen which sgbd to use. I also looked CITUS db that seems to solve this. Any idea?

Comment: you can checkout galera cluster (multi master replication).

Comment: When it comes to scalability there are so many things to consider before acting because there is no ultimate solution to fix every problem. So you should provide more information about application use cases, database size, number of concurrent user etc. For example in some cases sharding could be a good solution and for some others you should consider using microservices etc.